Google maps SDK doesn't show maps on iOS app
I am trying to implement Google Maps SKD to an iOS app.
The location dot, google logo, and go to my location button are visible, but not the maps.

I try different thinks but none of those works.
My code is:
AppDelegate
import GoogleMaps
import GoogleNavigation

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MY_KEY")
        return true
    }
....

ViewController
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GoogleNavigation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        guard status == .authorizedWhenInUse else {
            return
        }
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let location = locations.first else {
            return
        }

        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

In the console.cloud.google.com I set the project and the API key

and set the bundle ID.

I also have a billing account added to a project.
All other posts suggest:

The incorrect map_key -> I checked that I copied the correct key.
Not billing account -> I have one

What could be wrong here?
Xcode : 15.4
iOS : 15.0
map sdk: 9.0.0.0

Could you please create a support case in the Google Cloud Console to open a personalized communication channel?
